# storing API data array somehow

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have figured out how to insert my data array into the mysql table. (Thank you Hunsman).
Im wondering if there is neater tighter code that would accomplish what im doing. 
I notice that the way Im doing it only lets me insert top level of array results. The array displays correctly but unable to get sub level nodes with same name.Any Recommendations? Also wanted to post for anyone having similar problem. Took me some time to just find you guys.

```
<?php
function upsTrack($trackingNumber) {
$data ="<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
    <AccessRequest xml:lang='en-US'>
            <AccessLicenseNumber>AccessNumber</AccessLicenseNumber>
            <UserId>username</UserId>
            <Password>Password</Password>
    </AccessRequest>
    <?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
    <TrackRequest>
            <Request>
                    <TransactionReference>
                            <CustomerContext>
                                    <InternalKey>blah</InternalKey>
                            </CustomerContext>
                            <XpciVersion>1.0</XpciVersion>
                    </TransactionReference>
                    <RequestAction>Track</RequestAction>
            </Request>
    <TrackingNumber>$trackingNumber</TrackingNumber>    
    </TrackRequest>";
$ch = curl_init("https://www.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Track");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
// echo '<!-- '. $result. ' -->';
$data = strstr($result, '<?');
$xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($xml_parser, $data, $vals, $index);
xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
$params = array();
$level = array();
foreach ($vals as $xml_elem) {
if ($xml_elem['type'] == 'open') {
if (array_key_exists('attributes',$xml_elem)) {
     list($level[$xml_elem['level']],$extra) = array_values($xml_elem['attributes']);
} else {
     $level[$xml_elem['level']] = $xml_elem['tag'];
}
}
if ($xml_elem['type'] == 'complete') {
$start_level = 5;
$php_stmt = '$params';
while($start_level < $xml_elem['level']) {
     $php_stmt .= '[$level['.$start_level.']]';
     $start_level++;
}
$php_stmt .= '[$xml_elem[\'tag\']] = $xml_elem[\'value\'];';
eval($php_stmt);
}
}
curl_close($ch);
return $params;
}

if ($_POST['af0'] == 'xx1') {
if (preg_match('/^[a-z\d_]{4,80}$/i', $_POST['trackingNumber'])) {
    $cleanTrackingNumber = $_POST['trackingNumber'];
    $someArray = upsTrack("$cleanTrackingNumber");
    echo $someArray['RESPONSESTATUSDESCRIPTION'],    $someArray['SHIPPERNUMBER'],  $someArray['ADDRESSLINE1'],$someArray['CITY'],  $someArray['STATEPROVINCECODE'], $someArray['POSTALCODE'], $someArray['COUNTRYCODE'],$someArray['CODE'], $someArray['DESCRIPTION'], $someArray['VALUE'], $someArray['SHIPMENTIDENTIFICATIONNUMBER'], $someArray['PICKUPDATE'], $someArray['TRACKINGNUMBER'], $someArray['ACTIVITYLOCATION']['ADDRESS'] ['STATEPROVINCECODE'], $someArray['DATE'], $someArray['TIME'], $someArray['WEIGHT'];
} else {
    echo 'Invalid tracking number... sigh...';
}
}

?>
<?php
/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'localhost';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'testdb';

/*** mysql password ***/
$password = 'test123';

/*** database name ***/
$dbname = 'test';

try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
/*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
echo 'Connected to database<br />';

/*** set the PDO error mode to exception ***/
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
/*** begin the transaction ***/
$dbh->beginTransaction();


/***  INSERT statements ***/
$dbh->exec("INSERT INTO upstrackdb ( RESPONSESTATUSDESCRIPTION, SHIPPERNUMBER,   ADDRESSLINE1, CITY, STATEPROVINCECODE, POSTALCODE, COUNTRYCODE, CODE, DESCRIPTION, VALUE, SHIPMENTIDENTIFICATIONNUMBER, PICKUPDATE, TRACKINGNUMBER, ACTIVITYLOCATION, DELIVERYDATE, DELIVERYTIME, WEIGHT) VALUES ( '$someArray[RESPONSESTATUSDESCRIPTION]',  '$someArray[SHIPPERNUMBER]', '$someArray[ADDRESSLINE1]', '$someArray[CITY]', '$someArray[STATEPROVINCECODE]', '$someArray[POSTALCODE]', '$someArray[COUNTRYCODE]', '$someArray[CODE]', '$someArray[DESCRIPTION]', '$someArray[VALUE]', '$someArray[SHIPMENTIDENTIFICATIONNUMBER]', '$someArray[PICKUPDATE]', '$someArray[TRACKINGNUMBER]', '$someArray[STATEPROVINCECODE]',  '$someArray[DATE]', '$someArray[TIME]', '$someArray[WEIGHT]')");

/*** commit the transaction ***/
$dbh->commit();

/*** echo a message to say the database was created ***/
echo 'Data entered successfully<br />';
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
/*** roll back the transaction if we fail ***/
$dbh->rollback();

/*** echo the sql statement and error message ***/
echo $sql . '<br />' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Below are the results i get.

```
<!-- HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 02 Apr 2013 19:16:15 GMT
Server: Apache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 1808
Vary: User-Agent
Content-Type: application/xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TrackResponse><Response><TransactionReference<XpciVersion>1.0</XpciVersion>         </TransactionReference> <ResponseStatusCode>1</ResponseStatusCode>  <ResponseStatusDescription>Success</ResponseStatusDescription></Response><Shipment> <Shipper><ShipperNumber>975522</ShipperNumber><Address><AddressLine1>1700 SUNFLOWER AVE</AddressLine1><City>COSTA MESA</City><StateProvinceCode>CA</StateProvinceCode><PostalCode>92626   1505</PostalCode><CountryCode>US</CountryCode></Address></Shipper><ShipTo><Address><City>MOUNTAINSIDE</City><StateProvinceCode>NJ</StateProvinceCode><PostalCode>07092</PostalCode><CountryCode>US</CountryCode></Address></ShipTo><Service><Code>002</Code><Description>2ND DAY AIR</Description></Service><ReferenceNumber><Code>01</Code><Value>365357</Value></ReferenceNumber><ReferenceNumber><Code>01</Code><Value>4500137238</Value></ReferenceNumber><ShipmentIdentificationNumber>1Z9755220249869083</ShipmentIdentificationNumber><PickupDate>20130213</PickupDate><Package><TrackingNumber>1Z9755220249869083</TrackingNumber><Activity><ActivityLocation><Address><City>MOUNTAINSIDE</City><StateProvinceCode>NJ</StateProvinceCode><PostalCode>07092</PostalCode><CountryCode>US</CountryCode></Address><Code>M5</Code><Description>MAIL ROOM</Description><SignedForByName>SALEMI</SignedForByName></ActivityLocation><Status><StatusType><Code>D</Code><Description>DELIVERED</Description></StatusType><StatusCode><Code>KB</Code></StatusCode></Status><Date>20130215</Date><Time>093400</Time></Activity><PackageWeight><UnitOfMeasurement><Code>LBS</Code></UnitOfMeasurement><Weight>27.00</Weight></PackageWeight><ReferenceNumber><Code>01</Code><Value>365357</Value></ReferenceNumber><ReferenceNumber><Code>01</Code><Value>4500137238</Value></ReferenceNumber></Package></Shipment></TrackResponse>     --><pre>Array
(
[XPCIVERSION] => 1.0
[RESPONSESTATUSCODE] => 1
[RESPONSESTATUSDESCRIPTION] => Success
[SHIPPERNUMBER] => 975522
[ADDRESSLINE1] => 1700 SUNFLOWER AVE
[CITY] => MOUNTAINSIDE
[STATEPROVINCECODE] => NJ
[POSTALCODE] => 07092
[COUNTRYCODE] => US
[CODE] => 01
[DESCRIPTION] => 2ND DAY AIR
[VALUE] => 4500137238
[SHIPMENTIDENTIFICATIONNUMBER] => 1Z9755220249869083
[PICKUPDATE] => 20130213
[TRACKINGNUMBER] => 1Z9755220249869083
[ACTIVITYLOCATION] => Array
    (
        [ADDRESS] => Array
            (
                [CITY] => MOUNTAINSIDE
                [STATEPROVINCECODE] => NJ
                [POSTALCODE] => 07092
                [COUNTRYCODE] => US
            )

        [CODE] => M5
        [DESCRIPTION] => MAIL ROOM
        [SIGNEDFORBYNAME] => SALEMI
    )

[STATUS] => Array
    (
        [STATUSTYPE] => Array
            (
                [CODE] => D
                [DESCRIPTION] => DELIVERED
            )

        [STATUSCODE] => Array
            (
                [CODE] => KB
            )

    )

[DATE] => 20130215
[TIME] => 093400
[UNITOFMEASUREMENT] => Array
    (
        [CODE] => LBS
    )

[WEIGHT] => 27.00
)
```

Comment: That should be fairly easy.  Do you have a mysql database already set up for it?

Comment: yes database is ready. columns will be named according to array result names.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have everything you need. Parse the results, read in the list of email addresses and then INSERT them into the database (double check for duplicates first).

That array looks easily accessible. Its just a simple `"INSERT INTO ... VALUES( $array['DATE'], $array['TIME'] ...)"`

Heres a good intro to PDO in PHP: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html#7.1

Comment: Im not sure how to read them in. Any examples you can refer me to?

Comment: Can you show me the results of the API call? is it XML/json? just add it to your question, so everyone else can see it.

Comment: Actually, can you show me a print_r() of the array your code generates? Just add it to your question.

Comment: the xml array is at top of the example. I seem to get it back in no partucular strucure.

Comment: It shouldnt matter about the XML structure. As long as you can read the parts of your array using index's. i.e. echo $array['TRACKINGNUMBER'] you can then store that value in the database.